# How to use kaobook with French babel and keep the original bulleted list style?

Tags: itemize, babel, kaobook

I would like to use `kaobook` in French.
So, I use `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`.
In this way the bulleted list style is replaced by `--`.

How can I keep original theme in French please?

Comment: Since `kabook` isn't part of TeX Live it seems, I can't test, but try adding `\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}` to your preamble after loading `babel`.

Comment: Thanks ! That works :)

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to customize the French language settings using `babel`. The main command to setup things is `\frenchsetup`.

To undo the list modifications you can use the setting:

```
\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}
```

For a full set of commands, see the [package documentation](https://texdoc.org/pkg/babel-french).