# Enumitem identation issue

Tags: indentation, itemize, enumitem

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=1cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{(P1)}:]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The enumitem setting makes the item lose its indentation. Why? I tried this with no success:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=1cm}
\setlist{labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{(P1)}:]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that you're abusing the `itemize` label by overriding it explicitly. But this has nothing to do with using `enumitem` or not. Why not use an `enumerate` list and use `label={\bfseries (P\arabic*)}`?

Comment: This doesn't solve the indentation issue.

Comment: You haven't really explained what that issue actually is, since as I mentioned, the format has nothing to do with `enumitem`, and your sample documents don't really show what kind of indentation you're expecting. A large label will overlap the left margin, unless you explicity change the margins. So describe what indentation you are looking for and then we can help you achieve it.

Comment: With this minimal example, you'll see that `itemize` is by default indented with the first line of paragraphs. I want to keep that alignement. But if I set `\setlist{topsep=1cm}` with `enumitem`, the alignement is pulled back to the non-indented lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your inputs and further investigations I managed to get what I wanted with the following code (option `wide` was the key to the desired indentation):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchsetup{StandardLayout=true}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=1cm, wide, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=3\parindent, rightmargin=3\parindent} 


\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries (P\arabic*)}:]
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're having has nothing do do with `enumitem` and everything to with the fact that you're trying to fit a large label into a small space, so the label appears to change the indent but in reality it is simply expanding to the right. Presumably you expected the label to start left aligned at the indentation but that's not how list labels are usually set.

Here's your minimal example without loading `enumitem` and you can see that the effect is identical:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{itemize}
\item some text
\item[\textbf{(P1)}:] Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of first example]

So the solution to your problem (which is easily solved by using `enumitem`) is to adjust the margins of the list appropriately so that you have enough room for the larger label text *and* you have an indent of the items.  This requires changing both the `leftmargin` and the `labelindent` parameters.

Additionally, since you are misusing the `itemize` list to form what looks like a numbered list, you should really format the label of the list using `enumerate` instead of `itemize`. And in general, it's almost always a bad idea to supply an explicit label to a list item, and you should avoid doing it wherever possible.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries (P\arabic*):},leftmargin=3\parindent,labelindent=1.5\parindent]
\item some text
\item \lipsum[66]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of second example]

Comment: Mmh OK I know what happens. The document where I wanted to apply this setting had `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in the preambule. I didn't think that a language package could have an implication in such a layout problem. I didn't add it to my example. But if you try your minimal example with `babel` loaded you'll see that the label is indented and that the addition of `enumitem` creates what I describe.

Now if I keep `babel` with your solution it'll keep being non-indented.

Comment: @jfk See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683325/2693 for a solution to the `babel` problem. You can turn off the list modifications that `babel` French does.